# How to disable brackets highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How do I disable this?

[image]

Comment: Just curious here; why don't you like it?

Comment: When programming I get really distracted by the red brackets. It's annoying.

Comment: weird. how do you find the brackets in a complex multi level expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Settings, Styler Configurator, and change the "Brace Highlight" style.