# How to disable brackets highlighting in Notepad++, around an initial bracket

Tags: notepad++

I'm using NP++ version 6.8.1

(I use a beige background, with black text.  I changed the backround for the cursor to the same thing - works.  I see that if I start something with a parenthesis, like this sentence, though, it still gives me a white backround (the default) around it, in this case.  Annoying.  Great program, but why don't they put all of the settings for this all in one place?)

Related:

How to disable brackets highlighting in Notepad++ . . . [How to disable brackets highlighting in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/10366/how-to-disable-brackets-highlighting-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings, Styler Configurator, and change the "Brace Highlight" style.