# How to disable brackets "size change" in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm using NP++ version 6.8.1

In the following, if I put the cursor next to the bracket . . . between 3 and 4 . . . or 6 and 7 . . . and then move one character away . . . it makes the parentheses, square brackets, or curly brackets the normal size:

123(456)789
123[456]789
123{456}789

Any idea how to disable it, from making them the smaller size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable brackets highlighting in Notepad++](http://superuser.com/questions/10366/how-to-disable-brackets-highlighting-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open NP++.
- Settings -> Style Configurator.
- In the Style column, choose "Brace highlight style".
- Set its font size to match the font size you're using for regular text (check under "Default Style" for example).

[image: NP++ Style Dialog]

Comment: Thanks!  I un-checked Bold, changed it to what I'm using, Courier New 12 . . . now it's fixed